# How to separate regions of a GrayScale image equal to threshold value?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

I am trying to extract those regions of a Gray-Scale Image whose pixel value is equal to a threshold value. Is it possible to really do so using numpy functions.

I have already tried:

```
ig=cv2.imread("000000000078.png")
b= np.where(ig>84)
print(b)
plt.imshow(b[0])
```

The output is:

```
(array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 611, 611, 611]), array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 611, 611, 611]), array([0, 1, 2, ..., 0, 1, 2]))
```

which is a tuple of arrays. I tried plotting b[0] but it doesn't yield the regions as required by me. Is there any alternative to do so?

Comment: try to follow this site ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826832/convert-2-images-to-numpy-arrays-and-compare-pixel-by-pixel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert 2 images to numpy arrays and compare pixel by pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826832/convert-2-images-to-numpy-arrays-and-compare-pixel-by-pixel)

Comment: Thank you! It works fine but is there a way to separate the region from the image?

Comment: What do you mean by *"separate the region from the image"*? How will it look when separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...extract those regions of a Gray-Scale Image whose pixel value is **equal** to a threshold value.

You can get the job done using NumPy's [`equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html?highlight=equal).

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFzHW.png')

threshold = 32
region = np.equal(img, threshold)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
ax[1].imshow(region, cmap='gray')
for a in ax:
    a.set_axis_off()
plt.show(fig)
```

[image: results]

Notice that for the sake of this demo the cameraman image has been quantized so that there are only 4 different intensity values in `img`, namely 32,  64,  96, and 128.

As per the comments, I'm guessing the OP wishes to use `region` as the transparency layer mask of a PNG image. This is the relevant code to do so:

```
separate = np.stack([img, img, img, 255*np.uint8(region)], axis=-1)
io.imsave("filename.png", separate)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works fine but is there a way to separate the region from the image?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I want to basically extract the region separate from the image whose pixel value is equal to the threshold value.

Comment: In that case you could use `region` as the transparency layer mask of a PNG image.

Comment: I've just edited my answer to better suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems. First

```
ig=cv2.imread("000000000078.png")
```

gives you a 3-channel image, not grayscale. You need to load it grayscale:

```
ig = cv2.imread("000000000078.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Then, you can do thresholding, with either:

```
mask = cv2.threshold(ig, 84, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

or:

```
mask = np.uint8(ig>84)
```

Then the region can be extracted as:

```
filtered_img = cv2.bitwise_and(ig, ig, mask=mask)

plt.imshow(filtered_img)
```

Comment: Very nice, elegant answer

Comment: Thank you! It works fine but is there a way to separate the region from the image?

Comment: For each label, you can pick out all the pixels with that label (see the other answer). Then you can use [boundingRect](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7) to slice out the image part.

Comment: @QuangHoang See so far I have done the following.  `rt=img[region==True] `   `rect=cv2.boundingRect(rt)` But it returns as  rect = (0,0,1,36833) what does that mean? Am I doing any mistake?